# Android: improve the image quality on upload to the server

Tags: android, image, bitmap, base64, image-compression

I'm trying to upload an image to server in my Android application by converting it to a base64 string. In this case when I try to upload an image taken from my camera the quality of my image is largely reduced and is very much blurred. Can you please help me overcome this issue.

Here's my code:

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);

    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent   data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        Log.i("camera intent", "camera intent");

        bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 720, 1280, true);

        viewImage_imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        UploadImage_textView.setEnabled(true);


ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
    byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
    String file = Base64.encodeToString(data, 0);
    Log.i("base64 string", "base64 string: " + file);
    new ImageUploadTask(file).execute();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
This will give the thumbnail of the image taken by camera that's why you are seeing blurred image

```
 Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
 Uri tempURI = Uri.fromFile(<file path where you want to save image>);
 cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, tempURI);
 startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

then for this path you will get the actual image click by camera now upload that image to server.